# Improving on my e-mail writing skills

Tags: email

How can I improve my use of English when writing emails? English is my second language and I struggle to write emails as I lack experience.

Comment: Are you lacking grammar and sentence formulation/structure or mechanics like spelling and proper punctuation? Joe's answer is right on, and beyond that....just keep practicing and having a trusted colleague (or perhaps a professor) check it over if English is their native language. NOTE: Do NOT aim to speak grammatically correct or "perfect" English (it's looked down upon (i.e. pretentious) in business). Simple and "to-the-point" is the best in business :)

Answer (score 4):

> is there a way to improve writing emails?

Have you taken any ESL (English as a Second Language) courses? Many of those can really help improve your writing.

Some of them even concentrate on business writing skills.

If you are in the US, many Community Colleges offer such course. You might want to check their catalogs.

If not, many online sources such as Coursera offer the equivalents.

Comment: Quick FYI but Coursera no longer has free offerings (and are in the process of removing them). Might be worthwhile recommending different sources in the future as they are likely out of reach now for a lot of demographics.

Comment: @Codingo There are many free ESL resources available. However for language courses, I don't think such sources generally form a good *basis* for learning. They may be good supplements however. Sign up for an affordable course that suits you and then use additional free materials to supplement your learning.

Answer (score 1):

I agree completely agree with Joe, might I also recommend the following:

## Pause and review

When I was early in my career my mentor impressed upon me the importance of pausing to review every e-mail before I sent it. It's surprising how many errrors we make in our writing without noticing when we're  typing it out.

## Keep it simple, stupid!

The KISS model works great for e-mails. E-mails should explain a point clearly, but in a condensed manner. Can you use headings to make it easier to read? Can you use bullet points? If you keep things simple you'll find it easier writing quick, prompt sentences that don't test your use of the English language as much.

## Observe others

Get a feel for professional writing from your colleagues and those you look up to. The vibe of e-mail is quite different to that of formal writing or even professional document writing. Looking at what others are doing will help to improve upon your own knowledge.

Comment: Use spell check. For e-mails, make use of reply and quotation blocks to focus the conversation.